# Viewpager not scrolling in Coordinator layout

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

This is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:titleMarginTop="15dp">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/category_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="#f0f0f0"
                android:focusable="false" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/talview_color_1" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />  

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I am trying to pin the tablayout on top while scrolling. It doesn't work. More important point is, there is a listview in each viewpager fragment and the listview scrolling doesn't work in the listview.

Can anybody help

Comment: listview does not work with Co-ordinator Layout. read this blog http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use **NestedScrollView**, provided in Android Support Library v4, which is designed to work with **CoordinatorLayout**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView ...>
    <LinearLayout ...>
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

or **RecyclerView**, please note that the classic `ListView` doesn't work with CoordinatorLayout.

so inside your **viewPager** you need to have **NestedScrollView** or **RecyclerView**

Good luck